# Function is not defined even though it is? Simple hashing implementation for Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a hashing system using python for a class but I just couldn't really figure out why it keeps on returning "linear_probe" is not defined even though it is.

```
# hash table
from typing import Sized

class hash_table:

    # constructor
    # inputs: size (defaults to 8 if no arguments are provided)
    def __init__(self, size = 8):
        # self.table: empty hash table of indicated size
        self.table = (None,) * size
        # self.size: number of positions in table
        self.size = size


    # INSERTS value INTO HASHTABLE AT index
    # example: insert(5, 10) will place 5 into index#10
    def insert(self, value, index):
        temp = list(self.table)
        temp[index] = value
        self.table = tuple(temp)


    # function name: linear_probe
    # input: value- value to be inserted
    #start_index- where linear probing starts
    # output: returns the index of the hash_table that the value should be 
    #   inserted after linear probing
    # restrictions: Although you can implement this function with just one input, 
    # DO NOT alter the function heading
    # assumptions: value will always be an integer
    #   your table will always be big enough
    def linear_probe(self, value, start_index):
        if (start_index < (self.size - 1)) :
            next_index = start_index + 1
        else:
            next_index = 0
        valueG = self.table[next_index]

        while (self.table[next_index] != None) :
            if next_index < (self.size-1):
                next_index = next_index + 1
            else:
                next_index = 0
        return next_index
    


    # function name: insert
    # input: value- value to be inserted
    # output: Do not return anything. Just insert value into the proper position
    #   in self.table. Utilize linear_probe and insert in this function
    # assumptions: value will always be an integer
    #   your table will always be big enough
    def hash(self, value):
        slot = value % self.size #determines the slot number for value
        if (self.table[slot] == None):
            return self.insert(value, slot)
        else: 
            new_slot = self.linear_probe(value,slot)
            return self.insert(value,new_slot)

    # Already completed function!
    def get_table(self):
        return self.table


    # Already completed function!
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.table)
```

Our test cases will be running `hash_table()`, `hash()`, and `linear_probe()`. All of my `hash_table()` and `hash()` passed the test cases when called to run except for anything that uses `linear_probe()`. Any thoughts on why? Thanks!!

Edit:

The code **passed** these 2 test cases that were provided to us to check our work:

```
"""**********************************************************************"""

def checker(expected, actual):
    if expected == actual:
        print("CORRECT!")
    else:
        print("expected " + str(expected) + ", but got " + str(actual))

"""**********************************************************************"""

test1 = hash_table(5)
test1.hash(9)
test1.hash(25)
test1.hash(10)
test1.hash(14)
expected1 = (25, 10, 14, None, 9)

checker(expected1, test1.get_table())

"""**********************************************************************"""


test2 = hash_table(8)
test2.hash(5)
test2.hash(30)
test2.hash(52)
test2.hash(95)
test2.hash(45)
expected2 = (45, None, None, None, 52, 5, 30, 95)

checker(expected2, test2.get_table())
```

However, it failed the automated corrector and the TA gave the following feedback:

```
hash_table(8)
linear_probe(16, 0)error when running
hash(16)- CORRECT
linear_probe(107, 3)error when running
hash(107)- CORRECT
linear_probe(81, 1)error when running
hash(81)- CORRECT
linear_probe(315, 3)- CORRECT
hash(315)- CORRECT
linear_probe(198, 6)error when running
hash(198)- CORRECT
```

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Totally immaterial, but why is self.table a tuple rather than a list?  Also, what function do you call to look up an item in the table?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Please include the failing test case

Comment: Or at least show some example code, what results you got, and what results you expected to get.

Comment: New edits added!

Comment: You didn't give the traceback, you gave some sort of report which indicated that there was an error, but that report didn't specify what the error is.

Comment: Sorry the confusion, the post title itself is the error that is showing when you run the code:
""linear_probe" is not defined"

Comment: Did you (in response to the report from the TA) do something like just type `linear_probe(16, 0)` in the shell and generate the error you mentioned in the title? If so, you misunderstood the feedback. If not, you haven't given a [mcve] which leads to that error.

Comment: If you're using a online judge, can you give a link to it?

Answer (score 1):

```
linear_probe(16, 0)
```

Lines like this cause error because you are calling a function `linear_probe` which isn't defined.

At first you have to store the `hash_table` object in a variable,
like:

```
ht = hash_table()
```

Then call the test cases like this:

```
ht.linear_probe(16, 0)
```

*Ps. `hash()` works because there is a build-in function `hash`*

Comment: This is what I'm thinking too but I don't provide the test case.
But also how come the function hash() is running and seen as defined even without using the hash_table object unlike the linear_probe()

Comment: The professor uses an automated grader that uses that exact test case

Comment: There are problems in test cases all the time, it's nothing you did.

Comment: `hash()` is unlikely to refer to the built-in function. The testing code seems like it is testing *methods* but generates a report which you are misreading as if it were testing *functions*. I suspect that this answer misses the point entirely.

Comment: @JohnColeman then you should definitely add a answer with the point.

Comment: OP hasn't provided enough information to identify an answer. Nowhere does OP call a method as if it were a function and there is no reason to think that the testing code makes that error, but that is the possible error that your answer focuses on.

Comment: @JohnColeman hmm, why is `hash()` unlikely to refer to the built-in function?

Comment: Why would the built-in function satisfy the professor`s test cases? Why would the professor test the built-in function rather than the method that the students wrote?

Comment: Besides look at: `linear_probe(315, 3)- CORRECT`. Wouldn't that be incorrect if your interpretation was valid?

Comment: @JohnColeman You have some really fare points